# Consulta MongoDB retorna array vazio

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Tenho uma rota que recebe um parâmetro no formato yyyy-mm(ano-mes), recebo isto na função abaixo e faço uma busca no meu banco de dados mongoDB, porém retorna []:

```
const findYearMonth =  async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let data = [];
    const period = req.params.period;
    //console.log(`${typeof (period)} : ${period}`);
    data = await TransactionModel.find({yearMonth: period});
    JSON.stringify(data);
    if (!data) {
        res.status(500).send('Ocorreu um erro ao buscar valores');
    }
    else {
        res.send(data);
    }
  }catch (error) {
    res.send('Ocorreu um erro ao tentar encontrar as entradas:' + error);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Ao invés de usar parâmetro, use query que fica melhor, o que tá errado é que provavelmente o parâmetro não tá chegando na consulta por se tratar de uma String e aí o que você pode fazer pra testar é fazer a consulta com um valor fixo dentro do find (por exemplo find({ yearMonth: "2020-01" }), lembrando de alterar a rota, dessa forma que passei deve funcionar:

```
const findYearMonth = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let data = [];
    const period = req.query.yearmonth;
    //console.log(`${typeof (period)} : ${period}`);
    data = await TransactionModel.find({ yearMonth: period });
    JSON.stringify(data);
    if (!data) {
      res.status(500).send("Ocorreu um erro ao buscar valores");
    } else {
      res.send(data);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    res.send("Ocorreu um erro ao tentar encontrar as entradas:" + error);
  }
};
```

Altere a rota e no lugar do parâmetro coloque isso: ?yearmonth=2020-01

Ou então cria uma query na ferramenta que você está usando (Insomnia, Postman...)